# How to make a function wait X amount of time in LUA (Love2d)?

Tags: timer, lua, wait, love2d

I am very new to programming and coming from a "custom map" background in games like SC2. I am currently trying to make a platformer game in Love2d. But I wonder how I can make something wait X amount of seconds before doing the next thing.

Say I want to make the protagonist immortal for 5 seconds, how should that code look like ?

```
Immortal = true 
????????????????
Immortal = false
```

As I have understood there is no built in wait in Lua nor Love2d.

Comment: There is a "sleep" function `love.timer.sleep(5)`, but probably it's better to switch `Immortal` flag inside function `love.update(dt)`

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're interested in a temporary state for one of your game entities. This is pretty common - a powerup lasts for six seconds, an enemy is stunned for two seconds, your character looks different while jumping, etc. A temporary state is different than waiting. Waiting suggests that absolutely nothing else happens during your five seconds of immortality. It sounds like you want the game to continue as normal, but with an immortal protagonist for five seconds.

Consider using a "time remaining" variable versus a boolean to represent temporary states. For example:

```
local protagonist = {
    -- This is the amount of immortality remaining, in seconds
    immortalityRemaining = 0,
    health = 100
}

-- Then, imagine grabbing an immortality powerup somewhere in the game.
-- Simply set immortalityRemaining to the desired length of immortality.
function protagonistGrabbedImmortalityPowerup()
    protagonist.immortalityRemaining = 5
end

-- You then shave off a little bit of the remaining time during each love.update
-- Remember, dt is the time passed since the last update.
function love.update(dt)
    protagonist.immortalityRemaining = protagonist.immortalityRemaining - dt
end

-- When resolving damage to your protagonist, consider immortalityRemaining
function applyDamageToProtagonist(damage)
    if protagonist.immortalityRemaining <= 0 then
        protagonist.health = protagonist.health - damage
    end
end
```

Be careful with concepts like **wait** and **timer**. They typically refer to managing threads. In a game with many moving parts, it's often easier and more predictable to manage things without threads. When possible, treat your game like a giant state machine versus synchronizing work between threads. If threads are absolutely necessary, Löve does offer them in its [love.thread](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.thread) module.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use cron.lua for what you're talking about: https://github.com/kikito/cron.lua

```
Immortal = true
immortalTimer = cron.after(5, function() 
  Immortal = false 
end)
```

and then just stick `immortalTimer:update(dt)` in your love.update.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
function delay_s(delay)
  delay = delay or 1
  local time_to = os.time() + delay
  while os.time() < time_to do end
end
```

Then you can just do:

```
Immortal == true
delay_s(5)
Immortal == false
```

Of course, it'll prevent you from doing anything else unless you run it in its own thread. But this is strictly Lua as I know nothing of Love2d, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

I reccomend that you use hump.timer in your game,like this:

```
function love.load()
timer=require'hump.timer'
Immortal=true
timer.after(1,function()
Immortal=false
end)
end
```

instead of using `timer.after`,you can also use `timer.script`,like this:

```
function love.load
timer=require'hump.timer'
timer.script(function(wait)
Immortal=true
wait(5)
Immortal=false
end)
end
```

don't forget to add `timer.update`into function `love.update`!

```
function love.update(dt)
timer.update(dt)
end
```

hope this helped ;)

Download link:https://github.com/vrld/hump